# Rails: Multiple Query to Single Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to optimize below the code. because that makes the page quite slow. Is there any idea? I tried to remove iteration code, but I feel mentally paralyzed.

```
@cart_items_count_with_purchase = cart_items.select do |item|
  item.brand_user.sub_orders.where('created_at > ? AND product_id = ?', item.added_to_cart_at, item.product_id).
                             where(order_status: OrderStatus.paid).exists?
end.count
```

This is my way to solve the problem.

```
cart_items.joins(brand_users: :sub_orders).where(sub_orders: {order_status: OrderStatus.paid}).where('sub_orders.product_id IN (?)', cart_items.pluck(:product_id))
```

Comment: Can you please add model and associations? That might help in reducing the query further

Comment: Another piece of info that will help is what indexes the DB has for the fields.

Comment: Unrelated: your other question just got deleted. Please turn to the [help] and spent some serious time learning how/what to ask here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one with reduced line

```
product_ids = cart_items.pluck(:product_id)

cart_items.joins(brand_users: :sub_orders)
  .where(sub_orders: {order_status: OrderStatus.paid, product_id: product_ids})
```